# How can I add a floating label to a textarea?

Tags: html, css

I want that when a user comes and tries to type text in "textarea" the label goes up, and if they leave that area blank it comes back to the original position. If user typed something over there it will stay up there.

I tried this code with input box it is working fine, but when I try to do this with textarea and add some input in text area the label coming back down it need to be stay up there.

```css
textarea:focus~.floating-label,
input:not(:focus):valid~.floating-label {
  top: -40px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(100, 6, 6);
}

.scheme-des textarea {
  width: 90%;
  height: 50vh;
  resize: none;
  padding: 10px 20px 0 20px;
  font-size: 140%;
  color: #000;
}

.floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.form-float {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-float scheme-des">
  <textarea name="" class="inputText" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  <label class="floating-label">Description of scheme</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a blank placeholder and then add `textarea:not(:placeholder-shown)~.floating-label` selector to your first CSS rule.

Here is the result after doing that:

```css
textarea:focus~.floating-label,
textarea:not(:placeholder-shown)~.floating-label,
input:not(:focus):valid~.floating-label {
  top: -40px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(100, 6, 6);
}

.scheme-des textarea {
  width: 90%;
  height: 50vh;
  resize: none;
  padding: 10px 20px 0 20px;
  font-size: 140%;
  color: #000;
}

.floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.form-float {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-float scheme-des">
  <textarea name="" class="inputText" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder=" "></textarea>
  <label class="floating-label">Description of scheme</label>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. It is working now, can you please explain me how this work

Comment: The pseudo class `:placeholder-shown` selects the input or textarea while the placeholder is shown, which means that there is a placeholder value and no text has been entered to the field. I recommend you use the same method for your inputs.